# How to see the full row of the historical data obtained from Yahoo Finance through Jupyterlab

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab, yahoo-finance

I just started learning python today so bear with me on this one. Every time i tried to pull a the historical price from Yahoo Finance using pandas-datareader, the output has always been like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7LZM.png)

Based on the attached image, the output does not show the full row of the historical prices, how can i change it so it will provide the full row of the prices. I've tried to do the set_option, but it didn't work. (See the image on the link below)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQmEk.png)

Thank you very much

Comment: You should attach your code and dataset here instead of using picture.

Comment: oof sorry about that, rookie mistake

Answer (score 0):

try `.options` instead of `.set_options`

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = 4000
```